# How can I Delay Animations Randomly

Tags: css

I have a series of animations that are looping infinitely. Images scroll from left to right at different speeds, they also begin at different times.

My question is how can I delay the replaying of the animations? I've seen some workaraound in css, but i was hoping there was a class based jquery solution.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2jddfsjad/w40yhpbs/8/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@900&display=swap');
h1 {
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .02em black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.clouds {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.sonic {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  bottom: 150px;
  animation: move 1s linear 5s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  bottom: 150px;
  animation: move 2.5s linear 3s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.thirdCloud {
  bottom: 150px;
  left: -30%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 11s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.yoshi {
  bottom: 150px;
  left: -30%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 20s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    left: -30%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  from {
    left: 50%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="clouds">

  <div class="sonic"><img style="height:80px;" src="https://em.wattpad.com/86f7244f0e98b7a25564189215d6b0cb6e62036f/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f667761395f4f505a696a756c56513d3d2d3333353530393936302e313438383439363566396663343637383237373738313832393338312e676966?s=fit&w=720&h=720"
    /></div>
  <div class="secondCloud"><img src="http://img88.xooimage.com/files/e/8/8/runryurun-37e6c82.gif" /></div>
  <div class="thirdCloud"><img style="height:200px;transform: scaleX(-1);" src="http://www.fightersgeneration.com/np5/blaz-cs/sprites/2/litchi-walk.gif" /></div>
  <div class="yoshi">
    <img style="height:100px;" src="https://em.wattpad.com/143f34e59237d25e0aac050eaaac184bd38a1aa8/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f525553486b5a357a6179794453413d3d2d3337393836313835352e313461376664313864646630333431323439383832313539363730372e676966?s=fit&w=720&h=720"
    /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You could probably use the `Math.random(); * 10` to get a random value to use in assigning the `animation:` css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to post a separate answer as it performs a different function than the first one.

Using an `Array of Objects` you can define some "groups" with set properties such as `delay` and `duration`. In this example, I've use a `[min, max]` structure for flexibility.

These groups can have pre-defined delays and durations or you can generate them on load if necessary.

For this to work correctly, I've removed all `animation-delay` CSS values from the elements and rely on JS to handle this.

I've included some `console.log()` to help understand what's happening.

```js
// min and max values as seconds
var animationGroups = [
        {
            delay    : [0, 0], // don't delay as first element
            duration : [8, 9], // run animation between 8-9 seconds
            elements : [".sonic", ".yoshi"],
        },
        {
            delay    : [2, 4], // delay between 2-4 seconds
            duration : [4, 4], // run between 4-4 seconds (i.e. just 4 seconds)
            elements : [".secondCloud"],
        },
        {
            delay    : [0, 0], // start immediatly after previous
            duration : [4, 8], // run between 4-8 seconds
            elements : [".thirdCloud", ".sonic"],
        }
    ];

function animationQueueLoop(index){
    // check that index is within groups
    if(animationGroups.length - 1 < index){
        return;
    }
    
    var currentGroup = animationGroups[index];
    
    // check if there's no delay
    if(currentGroup.delay[0] === 0 && currentGroup.delay[1] === 0){
        runAnimation(currentGroup, index);
        return;
    }
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        runAnimation(currentGroup, index);
    }, getRandomBetween(currentGroup.delay[0], currentGroup.delay[1]));
}

function runAnimation(group, index){
    var duration = getRandomBetween(group.duration[0], group.duration[1]);
    
    // loop through the groups elements
    for(var i = 0, l = group.elements.length;i < l;i++){
        // add running class to start the animation
        $(group.elements[i])
            .removeClass("stopped")
            .addClass("running");
            
        console.log("Start: " + group.elements[i]);
    }
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        // loop through the groups elements
        for(var i = 0, l = group.elements.length;i < l;i++){
            var element = group.elements[i],
                $element = $(group.elements[i]);
                
            console.log("Request stop: ", element);
            
            // stop animation gracefully
            $element
                .one("animationiteration", function(){
                    // we have to reference `this` due to parent scope changing in the loop
                    // if you are using ES6 - you can reference $element if defined with `let`
                    $(this)
                        .addClass("pendingStop")
                        .one("animationend", function(){
                            console.log("Stop: ", this.classList[0]);
                            // once animation has stopped
                            // revert to its original position by removing the animation value
                            $(this)
                                .removeClass("pendingStop")
                                .removeClass("running")
                                .addClass("stopped");
                        });
                });
        }
        
        // run next animation group
        // NOTE: this doesn't wait for each element's animation to stop
        //       if you need to do this, you will have to keep a record
        //       of each elements state and then only run this once all
        //       have finished
        animationQueueLoop(index + 1);

    }, duration);
}

// example using sonic
$(document)
    .ready(function(){
        // DOM is ready
        animationQueueLoop(0);
    });

// get a random float between a min and max value
function getRandomBetween(minDelay, maxDelay){
  // use min value and add a random difference between min and max
  // multiply by 1000 to get in seconds
  return ( minDelay + (Math.random() * (maxDelay - minDelay)) ) * 1000;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@900&display=swap');
h1 {
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .02em black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.clouds {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.sonic {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  bottom: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  animation: move 1s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.secondCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  bottom: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  animation: move 2.5s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.thirdCloud {
  bottom: 150px;
  left: -30%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  animation: move 11s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.yoshi {
  bottom: 150px;
  left: -30%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  animation: move 20s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.running {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.pendingStop {
  animation-iteration-count:0;
}

.stopped {
  animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    left: -30%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  from {
    left: 50%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clouds">
  <div class="sonic"><img style="height:80px;" src="https://em.wattpad.com/86f7244f0e98b7a25564189215d6b0cb6e62036f/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f667761395f4f505a696a756c56513d3d2d3333353530393936302e313438383439363566396663343637383237373738313832393338312e676966?s=fit&w=720&h=720"
    /></div>
  <div class="secondCloud"><img src="http://img88.xooimage.com/files/e/8/8/runryurun-37e6c82.gif" /></div>
  <div class="thirdCloud"><img style="height:200px;transform: scaleX(-1);" src="http://www.fightersgeneration.com/np5/blaz-cs/sprites/2/litchi-walk.gif" /></div>
  <div class="yoshi">
    <img style="height:100px;" src="https://em.wattpad.com/143f34e59237d25e0aac050eaaac184bd38a1aa8/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f525553486b5a357a6179794453413d3d2d3337393836313835352e313461376664313864646630333431323439383832313539363730372e676966?s=fit&w=720&h=720"
    /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you want to repeat this, update the `index` back to 0 if it's outside the array range

Comment: this is it! thank you so much. so, i didn't quite get why i should change "index back to 0"? and do you mean i should change: "if(animationGroups.length - 1 < index)" to "if(animationGroups.length - 0 < index)"

Comment: @kylie2675647 close, inside that if statement, it simply `return;` to end the function. If you replace `return;` with `index = 0;` it will repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together an example using sonic from your code.
There are simpler ways to do this but the below code attempts to make it work smoothly.

There are 2 additional CSS classes:

- `pendingStop` - this "flags" the element to stop it's animation on next iteration
- `stopped` - this resets the animation to it's initial position

By listening to the `animation events` we can stop the animation at the end of an iteration and then resume it back at the start.

In this example, you can click the `Delay Sonic` button to make the animation stop, wait for a random time, then continue afterwards.

**NOTE:** this takes into account the css `animation-delay` property when "resuming" the animation. Due to this, I've changed the delay for `.sonic` to `1s` for clarity

```js
// min and max values as seconds
var minDelay = 2,
    maxDelay = 6;

// example using sonic
$(document)
    .on("click", ".stopSonic", function(){
    
        // handle the next animation iteration (for a smooth stop)
        $(".sonic")
            .one("animationiteration", function(){    
            
                // add pendingStop to set iteration count to 0 (stops on next iteration end)
                $(".sonic")
                    .addClass("pendingStop")
                    .one("animationend", function(){
                    
                        // once animation has stopped
                        // revert to its original position by removing the animation value
                        $(".sonic")
                            .removeClass("pendingStop")
                            .addClass("stopped");
                        
                        // get a random delay and remove stopped property
                        // animation will start after the delay
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".sonic")
                                .removeClass("stopped");
                        }, getRandomDelay(minDelay, maxDelay));
                    });
            });
    });

// get a random delay between a min and max value in seconds
function getRandomDelay(minDelay, maxDelay){
  // use min value and add a random difference between min and max
  // multiply by 1000 to get in seconds
  return ( minDelay + (Math.random() * (maxDelay - minDelay)) ) * 1000;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@900&display=swap');
h1 {
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .02em black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.clouds {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.sonic {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  bottom: 150px;
  animation: move 1s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  bottom: 150px;
  animation: move 2.5s linear 3s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.thirdCloud {
  bottom: 150px;
  left: -30%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 11s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.yoshi {
  bottom: 150px;
  left: -30%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 20s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.pendingStop {
  animation-iteration-count:0;
}

.stopped {
  animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    left: -30%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  from {
    left: 50%;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clouds">
<button class="stopSonic">Delay Sonic</button>
  <div class="sonic"><img style="height:80px;" src="https://em.wattpad.com/86f7244f0e98b7a25564189215d6b0cb6e62036f/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f667761395f4f505a696a756c56513d3d2d3333353530393936302e313438383439363566396663343637383237373738313832393338312e676966?s=fit&w=720&h=720"
    /></div>
  <div class="secondCloud"><img src="http://img88.xooimage.com/files/e/8/8/runryurun-37e6c82.gif" /></div>
  <div class="thirdCloud"><img style="height:200px;transform: scaleX(-1);" src="http://www.fightersgeneration.com/np5/blaz-cs/sprites/2/litchi-walk.gif" /></div>
  <div class="yoshi">
    <img style="height:100px;" src="https://em.wattpad.com/143f34e59237d25e0aac050eaaac184bd38a1aa8/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f776174747061642d6d656469612d736572766963652f53746f7279496d6167652f525553486b5a357a6179794453413d3d2d3337393836313835352e313461376664313864646630333431323439383832313539363730372e676966?s=fit&w=720&h=720"
    /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: this is a really wonderful solution. I think that this maybe very helpful for people looking at this thread. 

regarding exactly what I am looking for, i would like something like the following:

group 1 (sonic, characterX, characterY, characterZ) delays randomly between 8-9
group 2 (yoshi, characterA, characterB, characterC) delays randomly between 3-4

and because I am going to make more groups

group 3 ... between 10-11
group 4 ... between 1-2